# asp / asp mvc - how to trigger automatic client refresh

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-ajax

There are 3 clients that looks at same data instance, one of them edits data and submits on server, what are the mechanisms to make the other two clients instantly see the updated data ? 
I am thinking of some AJAX poll from time to time that will force page reload if there are changes or some page expire , is there anything else ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the jQuery ajax stack. This already is included when you make an ASP.NET MVC application in Visual Studio.

- [Timed Ajax calls with JQuery and ASP.NET](http://www2.aspcode.net/Timed-Ajax-calls-with-JQuery-and-ASPNET.aspx)
- [AJAX update content every X seconds](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/ajax-update-content-every-x-seconds.html)

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to use some [push-notification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) sistem for do client side refresesh. So with push notification your client will update only if erver has update data.

You can use [SignalR](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx) framework